# How to add certificate inside the route yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a certificate

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

It is stored in the variable after converting into the base64 encoding.

export certificateData=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

Am trying to create a route with the below Yaml and failing to get the certificate back inside the yaml :

```
cat <<EOF | oc apply -f -
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    openshift.io/host.generated: 'true'
spec:
  path: /ts/test
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: test1
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: https
  tls:
    termination: reencrypt
    destinationCACertificate: |
      ${certificateData} 
  wildcardPolicy: None
EOF
```

Comment: Its failing as the certificate is not in the proper format .. Please guide me to convert it into the proper format inside the yaml itself..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create secret of the certificate files and load in deployment as below

```
env:
- name: testCA
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: testCA.pem
      name: testSecretCert
```

inside the container it will be loaded into environment

Comment: Thank you .. But If we have it as an environment variable with the certificate encoded as Base64 String.. How to assign it to the destinationCACertificate as it takes only the certificate format ..

Comment: We can't add the env: inside the route.yaml . :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your yaml should be like the following:

- Set the different certificates or remove any entry which is not required
- In your question you mentioned that you store it in `base64` and this is your confution, if you would store it in secret it can be stores as `Opaque` which is `Base64`

```yaml
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  host: www.example.com
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: frontend
  tls:
    termination: reencrypt
    key: |-
      -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      [...]
      -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    certificate: |-
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      [...]
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    caCertificate: |-
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      [...]
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    destinationCACertificate: |-
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- <------------------ Not Base64
      [...]
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Thank you .. But I need to pass the certificate as the environment variable. Can you please suggest to me how to pass it as the environment variable ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for below

oc set env <object_type>/<object_name> KEY1=VALUE1 KEY2=VALUE2

oc set env dc/router ROUTER_SYSLOG_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1 ROUTER_LOG_LEVEL=debug

Below link has env variable for DEFAULT_CERTIFICATE, DEFAULT_CERTIFICATE

[https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#env-variables[enter](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#env-variables%5Benter) link description here][1](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#env-variables)